# Why does the button that is used to launch a custom macro stop working after I rename the subroutine?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I have a following macro that is added into LibreOffice itself (and not into specific document or spreadsheet):

```
REM Added into "My Macros & Dialogs: Standard: Module1"
REM (Tools > Macros > Edit Macros > ...)
Sub Foo
  MsgBox "hello world"
End Sub
```

And I have created a custom toolbar to run it by clicking a button on it:

1. Tools > Customize > Toolbars > Gear button > Add > Toolbar name = My own macros, Save in = LibreOffice Writer
2. Category = Macros > Expand the "My Macros" tree > Select the "Foo" command in the "Available Commands" list > Add it to the "Assigned Commands" list

**This works.***

> [image]

> [image]

But if I rename my subroutine in the code from `Foo` to `Bar`, the button stops working. It produces the following error:

> [image]

What I need to do to make it work? (To make the button work after the subroutine had been renamed)?

Comment: Just recreate toolbar and button with link to new subroutine

Comment: @JohnSUN Of course, I can. But it doesn't seem to be a really good solution, isn't it?

Comment: Renaming a procedure that is already referenced by some UI elements isn't a good idea either, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I found such reasoning useful and I don't like how this discussion evolves.

Comment: Consider this a feature of this office suite: for a control inserted into a spreadsheet sheet or a text document, you can easily change the macro - just go into editing the properties of this control. The fact is that a line like `vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.module.onBtnClick?Language=Basic&location=...` is saved in the document and can be easily changed. And everything related to toolbars (menus, hotkeys, etc.) is written to configuration files, for example, in `...user\config\soffice.cfg\modules\scalc\toolbar\standardbar.xml` - so change it using the user interface is difficult

Comment: By the way, this is a regular XML file, you can change the name of the procedure from `Foo` to new name in any text editor

Comment: Thanks, John. Well, each software has its quirks :-)

Comment: The office is constantly improving. Perhaps someday in the submenu of the Modify button, the item to modify the macro will appear.